# Do I need to turn off the breaker to install a pigtail adapter?

Tags: electrical, safety

Like the title says, do I *need* to turn off the breaker before installing a 2-prong to 3-prong "pigtail" adapter?

The instructions on the packaging state that I must, but my apartment has no discernable breaker box. The only thing that looks remotely like one is a very large set of boxes and meters on the back of the building, and those are locked up. I'd prefer to not have to go to my landlord just so I can plug in an adapter safely.

[I've seen it said](https://qr.ae/pvoJZd) that to take off the (potentially) grounding screw, you don't *need* to turn off the breaker, as you can find out if it's hot just by touching it. Since this is the only step for installing this adapter, logic would follow that I don't need to turn off the breaker to do it.

Comment: The instructions must say that since those people are not there to hold your hand.  It might be safe to do it with the power on, but people before you can have goofed it up enough so it is not safe.  Would check with your local power company and see if those adapters are legal.  In Canada they are banned.

Comment: What's the point anyway? The screw probably isn't even grounded.  Using a cheater when the ground is fake or bootlegged, is just asking to get shocked.

Comment: If you had to read the instructions on the packaging for an adapter, then yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in a tough situation. The *right* thing to do is to actually replace the 2-wire receptacle with a proper grounded 3-wire receptacle. But since you are in an apartment, you are not supposed to do that (work in a rental normally needs to be done by a licensed electrician), and in any case, you definitely can't do *that* without turning off the breaker.

Assuming this is a typical *external* adapter like [this GE adapter from Amazon](https://amzn.to/3NrFtQQ):

[image: GE 2 to 3 adapter]

you don't need to actually remove the cover plate, just the middle screw. But any time you actually do remove the cover plate you do need to turn off the circuit, because without the cover plate there are hot wires lurking less than an inch away from the front (and your fingers).

So remove the middle screw, plug in the adapter, and then test with a [Klein 3-wire tester from Amazon](https://amzn.to/3A3WZaM) (a.k.a., Magic 8-Ball):

[image: Klein receptacle tester]

If it shows *CORRECT* then you are done. Which also means that it would be very easy for an electrician to replace the receptacle with a modern 3-wire grounded receptacle.

If it shows *OPEN GROUND* then you do not have a good ground connection. Which means that the ground pin will *not* provide any actual protection.

If it shows *HOT/NEU REV* then you have a serious problem and should get the landlord in to fix it. And if the landlord is smart then they'll have the electrician put in a 3-wire grounded receptacle at the same time rather than simply rewire the existing receptacle.

Comment: Before you even remove the cover plate screw can't you plug in the adaptor with the 3-prong tester already plugged in to see if the hot and neutral are correct? If they are, then proceed to remove the screw, insert the adaptor, replace the screw, reinsert the 3-prong tester to see if there is a  path. Of course, this would not verify that the ground path would trip the breaker in the event of a short.

Comment: Of course, using a non-contact voltage tester would tell if the hot and neutral were correct.

Comment: Would using an ohmmeter between neutral and ground screw reveal whether there was a good enough ground path to trip the breaker in the event of a short?

Comment: Yes on the first 2. Probably on the 3rd because a thin wire will burn up before breaker trip which is why there are ground wire size requirements but in old stuff sometimes anything can happen.

Comment: Correct may also indicate a bootlegged ground, th device can't tell the difference.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer. I have ordered a tester, and am hopeful for a correct grounding.

Comment: Before you go https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/7367/michael-karas wants to know are those pictures your property, or what is the source.

Comment: @knowitall - [Must we cite pictures from the internet?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239653/must-we-cite-pictures-from-the-internet) "If you have the information and can provide it, do so - it's just good manners." - "at least provide *the Internet* the courtesy of attributing the original source." ... which they did via the links provided.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I was told by the Moderator it is rule to post the source, unless it is your property. Maybe he is just picking on me.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Did you draw that picture? If not it is expected that your answer provide attribution to where / whom the picture came from. Please update your answer to comply with SE policies. – 
Michael Karas
♦

Comment: *Must we cite pictures from the internet* is my own 7yo question, asked when I was in a similar position as them. You just happen to be a bystander in the only current drama on DiY.

Answer (score 0):

**No need to turn off power for this.**

Plug in the 3 prong outlet and **IMPORTANT** screw the metal latch (pig tail) sticking out at the bottom of the plug.

The screw acts as ground, been screwed in a metal box in the wall, that **supposed** to be grounded.

[image: ground]

Now there are few what-If's:

What if is a plastic box.

What if it is a metal box but not grounded ?

If you just had a multimeter you could verify.

Comment: Metal box is not a guarantee of a complete ground path.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact should it be grounded, or there is no code for that ?

Comment: It **should** be grounded. But since grounded receptacles weren't used, it is possible there is no ground wire or that it was never connected properly. Especially since metal boxes do not necessarily mean conduit.

Comment: Metal boxes were installed for many years before ground wires were a thing. Presence of actual grounding (not bootlegged from neutral) must be confirmed when dealing with two-prong outlets, never assumed.

Answer (score -2):

Do you "need" to?  No, there are some foolish people who choose to work in electrical equipment while it's "live".  We often call them "walking dead" and I don't recommend this at all.

Either BE SAFE while working with electricity or leave it to people who will work safely.

Comment: Would add "untrained" to the foolish.